# JAVA - Checking for NULL value from a result set

Tags: java, jdbc, null, resultset

I need to check if a value extracted from a result set is not NULL before using it.
I found this solution

```
int value = 0;
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
if (rs.next()) {
   value = rs.getInt("FIELD");
   if (!rs.wasNull()) {
       // use NOT NULL field value
   }
}
```

but I need to check the field value directly, with no assignment to a variable since the data type is not known in advance.

To explain better the goal, here my code:

```
Method method_one = null, methodResultSet=null;

switch(field_type){
    case "int":
       method_one = clazzAbstractClass.getDeclaredMethod("setValue_INT", short[].class,String.class,int.class);
       break;
   case "float":
       method_one = clazzAbstractClass.getDeclaredMethod("setValue_FLOAT", short[].class,String.class,float.class);
       break;
   case "double":
       method_one = clazzAbstractClass.getDeclaredMethod("setValue_DOUBLE", short[].class,String.class,double.class);
       break;
}

methodResultSet = clazzResultSet.getDeclaredMethod("get"+field_type.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + field_type.substring(1), String.class); // e.g. rs.getInt

// current call with NO CHECK on NULL                   
method_one.invoke(my_object, methodResultSet.invoke(rs, FIELD_NAME);
```

In a few words, the code creates something like that:

```
my_object.setValue_INT(rs.getInt("FIELD"))
```

NB: getInt uses 0 as default value for NULL value

My goal is to directly put either the FIELD VALUE or NULL as argument of the setValue_INT function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your probably could try using of `ResultSet.getObject(int columnIndex)` method. From its [JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html) description:

> This method will return the value of the given column as a Java
>   object. The type of the Java object will be the default Java object
>   type corresponding to the column's SQL type, following the mapping for
>   built-in types specified in the JDBC specification. **If the value is an
>   SQL NULL, the driver returns a Java null.**

Comment: OK. Can the following solution be correct: `if(rs.getObject(NAME) != null)
      methodAbstractClass.invoke(my_object, methodResultSet.invoke(rs, NAME);
     else
      methodAbstractClass.invoke(my_object, null);`

Answer (score 2):

`ResultSetMetaData.getColumnType(int column)` returns an int value specifying the column type.

```
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
if (rs.next()) {
   if (!rs.wasNull()) {
       ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();
       //Below, i ----> column number of the column 'FIELD'.
       int type = rsmd.getColumnType(i);
        if (type == Types.VARCHAR || type == Types.CHAR) {
            System.out.print(rs.getString());
        } else {
            System.out.print(rs.getLong(i));
        }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since checking for NULL this way is tedious, I use the helper methods like the following:

```
private static Integer getResultSetInteger(ResultSet resultset, String colName) throws SQLException {
    int v = resultset.getInt(colName);

    if (resultset.wasNull()) {
        return null;
    }

    return Integer.valueOf(v);
}

private static Double getResultSetDouble(ResultSet resultset, String colName) throws SQLException {
    double v = resultset.getDouble(colName);

    if (resultset.wasNull()) {
        return null;
    }

    return Double.valueOf(v);
}
```

Then, instead of

```
my_object.setValue_INT(rs.getInt("FIELD"));
```

you write

```
my_object.setValue_INT(getResultSetInteger(rs, "FIELD"));
```